# @AttributeOverrides and @Embeddable not working

Tags: java, hibernate

This is from **Hibernate Recipies** book at chapter 3 first  question when I am trying to run I am getting the following error **Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.fun.hibernate.auto.idgen.Order column: address (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")**

Here is the code

```
@Entity
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert=true, dynamicUpdate=true)
@Table(name="ORDERS")
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="orderSequence" )
@SequenceGenerator(name="orderSequence",sequenceName="ORDERSEQ")
private Long id;


private Contact weekdayContact;
private Contact holidayContact;
public Order() {

}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Contact getWeekdayContact() {
    return weekdayContact;
}
public void setWeekdayContact(Contact weekdayContact) {
    this.weekdayContact = weekdayContact;
}

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="recipient",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_RECIPIENT")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="phone",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_PHONE")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="address",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_ADDRESS"))
})
public Contact getHolidayContact() {
    return holidayContact;
}
public void setHolidayContact(Contact holidayContact) {
    this.holidayContact = holidayContact;
}
}
```

Embeddable Object

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact {

private String recipient;
private String phone;

private String address;
public Contact() {

}
@Column(name = "WEEKDAY_RECIPIENT")
public String getRecipient() {
    return recipient;
}
public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
    this.recipient = recipient;
}
@Column(name ="WEEKDAY_PHONE")
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}
public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
@Column(name ="WEEKDAY_ADDRESS")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

Any ideas how to solve this??????????????

Answer (score 0):

Reading the Hibernate Recipes book cited above I could easily reach the exactly point you described on your question.

I couldn't create the same environment that you are working on, so I had to read and interpret what the book says about mapping by annotations and by external configuration files (XML).

By studying your code and the book chapter I think that there are a high probably that you doing some redundancy in the mapping your embedded object, so there is what I think it's the exactly(or close to it) problem:

In the configuration file the book says to create the manual mapping by tags, just like this:

```
        <component name="weekdayContact" class="Contact">
            <property name="recipient" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_RECIPIENT" />
            <property name="phone" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_PHONE" />
            <property name="address" type="string" column="WEEKDAY_ADDRESS" />
        </component>
        <component name="holidayContact" class="Contact">
            <property name="recipient" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_RECIPIENT" />
            <property name="phone" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_PHONE" />
            <property name="address" type="string" column="HOLIDAY_ADDRESS" />
        </component>
```

Just above this the book also says that you need to create the mapping by annotations:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="recipient",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_RECIPIENT")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="phone",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_PHONE")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="address",column=@Column(name ="HOLIDAY_ADDRESS"))
})
public Contact getHolidayContact() {
    return holidayContact;
}
```

So, I think that's there only two possible things happening here:

1. You are mapping the embedded object in the XML file and in the class. In this case you should do it just by one type, preferably by annotations.
2. I could see that your code differs that the one the book states, and this may be causing the failure. In this case you should read again your whole code and see if there's any differential than the book one, and then correct it to be working just like it's written in the examples.

That's it, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was doing through annotations and not using any kind of mapping file. Any ways I found out the answer, as you can see in book(only JPA annotations part) they are asking to mention column for weekdayContact in value object and overriding  and annotating for holidayContact in Entity class. Instead of that i have overriden both of them using AttribbuteOverides in Entity Class, and it is working fine.